# access object name within the object with this

Tags: javascript

in i want to alert the 'image' which is the object name, how can i access with `this` ?

```
Objectswitch={
    'image':
    {
        addCount:function(){
            alert('count');
        },
        addCountandCreate:function(){
            this.addCount();
            alert(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add the name as a property of the object:

```
var imageObj = {
  name: "image",
  addCount:function(){
    alert('count');
  },
  addCountandCreate:function(){
     this.addCount();
     alert(this.name);
  }
}
```

you can then reference that object from within another, of course:

```
ObjectSwitch = {
  "image": imageObj
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, you can't with that structure.  `this` refers to the object: `{addCount:, addCountandCreate:}` and JS has no way to say `this.parentObject` (which doesn't make sense anyway since an object can have multiple references)

Comment: *"JS has no way to say this.parentObject"* Doesn't, can *can't*, because there can (of course) be multiple properties and variables pointing to it.

Comment: @TJ - Just edited my most to say that exact same thing (before I saw your post) :P